# Google AdSense Ad not showing up in WordPress Blog

Tags: javascript, adsense

I cannot get a Google AdSense ad to show up in a WordPress blog I'm working on. The ads have been approved and I entered the code (and double-checked the code to make sure I had it right). The code is as follows:

```
<div id="ads_sidebar">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7308560787788569";
/* Makeup */
google_ad_slot = "0956930336";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
```

The comments (i.e. `<!--`) were part of the code that Google provided. I tried without those as well and it didn't work. The CSS for the div is as follows:

```
#ads_sidebar{
position:absolute; top:0; left:-190px; background:transparent; font:normal 12px/14px 
"Trebuchet MS","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial; padding:20px 20px 30px 5px; 
display:inline; float:left; _margin:0 auto; height:600px; width:120px;
}
```

I know the div shows correctly because I tested the code with a `border:1px solid black;` and it displayed on the screen.

I also know that sometimes Google Ads don't show up to the owner of the account if you're signed in so I tried from a different browser. Still no luck. Anybody have any ideas why it hasn't shown up? Thanks.

Comment: *Where* are you putting this code? Do you see any errors on the page? What does the browser console show? Even then, I'm not convinced this is a WP question and it will likely be closed ...

Comment: Yep sorry. It was on a WordPress blog so I was concerned that maybe I was having a problem with the javascript conflicting with something on my page. All I had to do was be patient and let it run it's course. Sorry, didn't mean to clutter up the board!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to wait at least 30 - 60 minutes after you placed the ads, because it will take some time for the ads to adjust to your website (content wise).

You can already check your website if the code is already there by following these steps:

1. Go to the page where your ads suppose to be
2. Check the source code
3. Look for your Adsense code and / or your publisher number "ca-pub-7308560787788569"

Good Luck

~ LetUsLook

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it. I just needed to be patient. Thanks!